# AngularJS Passing parameter to directive's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this basic set

HTML

```
<linear-chart chartData="myArray" height="666"> </linear-chart>
```

JS
    ...

```js
...
app.directive('linearChart', function($window){
   return{
      restrict:'EA',
      template:"<svg  width='850' height={{myHeight}} ></svg>",     ******-> if I hard code height with number all great but when trying to pass as arg it goes kapput with/without the quotes
      
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
           var salesDataToPlot=scope[attrs.chartData];
           

   scope.myHeight = attrs.height;
   console.log('h passed=', scope.myHeight);    *****-> prints out the proper value 666
...
```

when try to pass the height as an argument I get this
Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "{{myHeight}}".

Something so innocent but I cannot find a similar situation/answer or am I passing it the value to the template the wrong way???

**UPDATE**

Thanks bhantol and Kristiyan  although the properties in Chrome were being set still in the directive the angular code was still not translating the scope.myHeight, I stepped thru the Chrome debugger and after a few trials I found out a work around and it is here

```js
...
template: function(scope,elem)
  {  var myTemp = '<svg  width="850" height="' + elem.height + '"></svg>';
      return myTemp;
  },
...
```

Comment: Try `template:'<svg  width="850" height="{{myHeight}}"></svg>'`

Comment: Thanks bhantol but I get the same error

Comment: Can you create aplunker ? Or show the full code in some gist/github repo

Comment: Working fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/OOU5EiVLl0enZrNK0DDX?p=preview

Comment: I am doing an actual drawing on the svg HTML5 graphics tag,  in your plunker literally it works as it did on my console.log, but it seems like somehow the svg tag expects a number and cannot see it. Not sure how to get that in in the template

Comment: If you inspect the svg element you will see the height properly set to 666. So I suspect something is the problem. You can fork and fill in your values in that plnkr and try and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your double quotes to single quotes on the following like from:

```
template:"<svg  width='850' height={{myHeight}} ></svg>",
```

to:

```
template:'<svg  width='850' height={{myHeight}} ></svg>',
```

That way Angular takes the whatever value myHeight holds rather than taking myHeight as a string. More information can be found in the AngularJS Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive); check the **Template-expanding directive** guide

Comment: Hope that helps